# how to run methods on background programme

Tags: java, eclipse, scenebuilder

I'm working on a java application and I have a method that I want it to work every 30 minutes in the background please help me I've been hearing about threads or something like that? 
ps: I'm using eclipse

Comment: Post some relevant code as well for better help, meanwhile you may look at javax.swing.Timer for scheduled job like this

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Spring-boot? You could then simply annotate your method with `@Scheduled`
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Answer (score 0):

You could use threads, a thread is something who run independently of your program, so you can create a thread who will live is own life and each 30 minutes, will wake up and do what you want it does.

Here is a little explanation about [thread in java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm)